# Bash/Perl chained SSH commands (A to B to C)

Tags: perl, bash, ssh

I run a bash shell on machine A running via ssh a perl shell on machine B, requesting via ssh a command result to machine C. I can't get the result shown in tty on machine A...

Here is a summary of several thousands of line codes :

**1) bash shell "A" on machine "A": NOK**

```
...  
ssh -p port userb@machineB "scriptB.pl"  
...
```

**2) perl scriptB.pl" on machine "B": OK**

```
...  
# my $user = qx|$ssh_cmd| if ($ssh_connection_ok);  
my $user = qx#$ssh_cmd# if ($ssh_connection_ok);  
...
```

**3) bash command $ssh_cmd on machine "C": OK**

```
cat /my_dir/my_file | grep this_user | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1 | tr
```

Run as standalone, step2 and step3 are showing the expected result but running scriptB.pl from machine A does not return the expected data. I do not use Net::SSH2 at the moment but qx. Might be an issue in the client ssh setup.

Thx in adv.

Comment: yes, $? returns 0 when running scriptB on machine B but 65280 when run from machine A. How shall I interpretate this .. ? I also ran scriptB locally on machine B, and I get the expected value from there. As well as running the cmd on machineC. I also tried adding $|=1 after the perl shebang, no diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who would face the same issue :

Context on server A :

```
ssh user_foo@serverB "ssh user_bar@serverC"
```

To get it working in command line or in the shell, the ssh agent shall be forwarded, eg using the ssh option "A" (see ssh man page), like :

```
ssh -A user_foo@serverB "ssh user_bar@serverC"
```

Answer (score 1):

If failure matters, check the exit status of an external program. To get the exit status in `$?`—see the [perlvar documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)—use `$? >> 8` or [`WEXITSTATUS`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#WEXITSTATUS) from the POSIX module.

In your case, 65280 corresponds to an exit status of 255, and according to the [ssh manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

> **ssh** exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

I'm surprised you aren't seeing some diagnostic from the failed ssh. Are you redirecting the standard error to `/dev/null`, or is it getting lost in a flood of other output?

Are you using unencrypted ssh keys or rhosts authentication? Are you forwarding the connection to your authentication agent (`ForwardAgent` in your [`~/.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config))? For debugging, can you cut out the middle man and issue the command to host C directly from host A?

Comment: redirection oh the output to /dev/null: no

Comment: ssh is enabled with dsa keys and chained with keychain from 1 machine to the next. ForwardAgent: no.

Comment: Issuying the bash command to host C directly from host A (also via ssh): yes it works. (I need to check removing some ssh options in the shell, like "-C" for compression)

Comment: @hornetbuzz What are you seeing on the standard error? It may help to discard the standard output: `ssh ... >/dev/null`

Comment: On the way to find the root cause : I get a "Permission denied (publickey,password)." when running the perl scriptB on machine A. The script is denied to ssh access to machine C. But not when I run the script on machine B. I have checked the code runner on machine B when launched from machine A, it's the same user than when I get scriptB running "manually" from machine B. Do not know if it's clear..